# My codeigniter callback does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code in controller is

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('periodStartFrom','Salary Period StartFrom', 'trim|required|callback_dateValidate');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) 
        {
            $this->load->view('pages/salary_period');
        }        
        else
        {}
```

My custom formvalidation file is:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

  }

public function dateValidate($date) 
{

    $rgexp = '/(^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-8])[.](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[.]   (0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[.](0[4,6,9]|11)))[.](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[.]02[.](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)/'   ;
if(preg_match($rgexp,$date) === 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
            else{return FALSE;}                
 }
 }
```

Loaded MY_Form_validation in controller construct function:

```
$this->load->library('My_Form_validation');
```

The problem is when I write the function dateValidate within controller, it works, I is not working from MY_Form_validation. Everytime displays the error message that I set in form_validation_lang.php

I could not locate the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you define them in MY_Form_Validation, remove 'callback_' like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('periodStartFrom','Salary Period StartFrom', 'trim|required|dateValidate');
```

On other hand, load Form_validation library without MY_. MY_ will be loaded itself.

```
$this->load->library('Form_validation');
```